# create trigger with ' insert into.. select...' statement

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I am writing an after insert trigger which inserts data to list_of_requests table taking the data from emp_sup table.

```
create trigger trig_lor
after insert 
on employee_skillset
for each row begin
    insert into list_of_requests (APPROVER1,APPROVER2,LOGDATE) 
    select sup1,sup2,'#dateFormat(now(),"yyyy/mm/dd")#' from empsup
        where empno=NEW.employee_number
end
```

This is giving error as: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'trigger trig_lor after insert on employee_skillset for each row begin inse' at line 1`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but give it a try.

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists trig_lor //
create trigger trig_lor
after insert 
on employee_skillset
for each row
begin
insert into list_of_requests (APPROVER1,APPROVER2,LOGDATE) 
select sup1,sup2,curdate() from empsup where empno=NEW.employee_number;
end; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @sanjeev - Works for me. Are you running the commands directly in mySQL?

Comment: @leigh i'd say he is running this in a `cfquery` judging by the use of `#dateformat#` in the question - maybe a permissions problem on the datasource?

Comment: @Antony - You are probably right about using `cfquery`. I am just not sure you can use the `delimiter` command in a cfquery. I want to say no, but cannot find a reference off hand.

Comment: @Antony - Here it is. This confirms you cannot use it within a `cfquery`. The `delimiter` command is only understood by my sql clients. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42318